# How to display the list with "" in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

In Python it is allowed to use both '' and "" in the list.

And when I generate a list like:

```
map(str,list1)
```

the default display uses ' ':

```
mylist = ['1','2','3']
```

Now I want to display like :

```
mylist = ["1","2","3"]
```

How can I make it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Python defaults to `'` unless there's a `'` in the string.

Comment: not sure why do you need it, but here's a very naive approach: `str(mylist).replace(" ' ", ' " ')` (<- `replace` without the spaces)


:p

Comment: If you can explain why you want double quotes instead of single quotes, we can help better with an answer.  For example, perhaps you need JSON? In which case, json.dump() is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just replace the output after converting the list to a string:

```
>>> x = ['a','b']
>>> x
['a', 'b']
>>> y = str(x)
>>> y
"['a', 'b']"
>>> y.replace("'", '"')
'["a", "b"]'
```

note however, this is a string now, not a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built-in string.format(). Try this:

```
>>> Mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> Mylist = ['"{}"'.format(x) for x in Mylist]
```

This will replace the {} with each element in Mylist and it to the new list , in its new format. You will get this result :

```
>>> Mylist
['"1"', '"2"', '"3"']
>>> print Mylist[0]
"1"
```

Hope this is what you are looking for, best of luck!